# Is it common for a language to evalute undefined as equal to false? If so, why is this done?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, ruby

**UPDATE:** Question still unanswered. **@Alastair_Pitts:** Unless I'm missing something, it's a two part question. The second part, "If so, why is this done?" and not been answered.

---

Believe the question is clear, but if you have any questions -- just let me know. Thanks!

**undefined = unknown** and is a reference to system based on ternary logic.

---

**Reference:**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic

Comment: **EDIT:** Find it interesting that one question I ask gets **10 views** in the same amount of time as this one, and gets **3 up votes** -- but this question with **131+ views** gets **zero up votes** -- **Please explain why, I don't get it?** ... **Other question:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920193/what-would-be-an-example-of-an-anaphoric-conditional-in-lisp

Comment: 3/10 people thought the other question was a good question.

Comment: @Blunders: I rolled back to a previous version of your question as it's not the place to discuss unrelated questions. If you have an issue around this, meta is a place to discuss it.

Comment: Users browse by tags. You used a lot of popular tags for this question, so a lot of views.

Comment: **@BalusC:** That might make sense if there were no answers, answer-comments, answer-up-votes -- but that's not the case. Still makes no sense to me, oh, well... :-)

Comment: **@Alastair_Pitts:** Well done... :-)

Comment: I believe your question is an example of weak typing.

Comment: @blunders: upvotes are a function of the perceived value of the question or answer, not the number of views.

Comment: **@Bob_Jarvis:** That might make sense if there were no answers, answer-comments, answer-up-votes -- but that's not the case. Still makes no sense to me, oh, well... :-)

Comment: @blunders: I rolled back the question as the question has been answered.

Comment: **@Alastair_Pitts:** Unless I'm missing something, it's a two part question. The second part, "If so, why is this done?" and not been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many, if not most, languages values are either falsy, meaning that something doesn't exist or lacks value, or truthy, meaning that something exists or has value. The list of falsy values is usually: (these evaluate to false)

1. 0 (zero, the number)
2. '' (an empty string)
3. null (if this value exists)
4. undefined (if this value exists)
5. false/False (if it has a boolean type)

Anything else is truthy and evaluates to true.

**Edit:** Made the answer a bit less biased towards JavaScript

Comment: this seems really really javascript-y

Comment: Thats because it is (Professionally, I write A LOT of JavaScript so its rules come to mind first, generally) Python's rules are similar, though

Comment: **@indieinvader:** +1 Yes, your edit did make it more clear, and less JS biased. Thanks!

Comment: @indie, C#, C/C++, Java, Ruby, Lua, lisp, and many many languages do not evalute those values to false. You are completely wrong when you say "most" or even "many".

Comment: The empty string one can swing so many ways depending on language. The others seem fair in the general senese.

Comment: **@banister,@Martin_York:** Thanks for pointing out the conflicts in truthy/falsy eval difference between JavaScript and other languages.

Comment: For completeness's sake, there are some languages (*e.g.*, Haskell) where `True` is truthy, `False` is falsy, and everything else *isn't a boolean* and can't be used in conditionals.  (Or it's the error value and you get an infinite loop/an exception.)

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is no, most languages do not consider "undefined" to be the same as false. Of course it's important to know the particulars of a language to understand how it handles `true`, `false`, `NULL` (or `nil`), etc.

You tagged this with Ruby, so here are some Ruby examples:

```
>> x # raises NameError: undefined local variable

>> x = nil # initializes x and assigns the value nil

>> x == true # false

>> x == false # false (in Ruby nil is not false, but see below)

>> x.nil? # true

>> x ? true : false # false -- Ruby treats nil values as false in conditions

>> x = 1 # now x has a value

>> x.nil? # false

>> x ? true : false # true
```

As to "why evaluate undefined as false", it can be handy when you need to know a variable is defined before you use it. For example in Ruby you often see this:

```
if x && x == "some interesting value"
  do_important_thing
end
```

If `x` is undefined, the first part of the condition returns false and the statement short-circuits. Which is much cleaner than:

```
if x.nil?
  if x == "some interesting value"
    do_important_thing
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `x && x.y == "some interesting value"`?

Answer (score 2):

I have only come across this with Javascript and when this occurs, the value is actually a string defined as 'undefined'

If you were to run a test on this:

```
if (someVar==true) {
document.write('True');
} else if (someVar==false) {
document.write('False');
} else {
document.write('Other');
}
```

It will output 'Other' as opposed to true or false - don't know if this helps...

Comment: Your first comment is not right (undefined is not a string, though if you cast it to a string, you will get the string `"undefined"`) but your second point is true for undefined *and* strings. This: `var x, y = "s"; alert(x == true || x == false); alert(y == true || y == false); alert(typeof x); alert(typeof y);` outputs false, false, undefined, string.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily!

It depends on what you mean by "undefined". If you mean "uninitialized", then the answer is no.

In C or C++, assume there is a statement

```
int x;
```

in function scope. After the statement is executed, `x` is a legal integer variable, but it is not initialized. `x` can take any value. If it takes value `0`, then it is `false`; for all other values (*whose probability is much higher*), it is `true`. However, at the end, it does not matter what value `x` actually acquires. From the program correctness standpoint, the it is "*undefined behavior*."

Though it is not provided by the language, it is also possible to implement a tri-state, e.g. true, false, unknown. See, for example, the `tribool` in [Boost tribool](http://www.systomath.biz/include/Boost-1_34/doc/html/boost/logic/tribool.html).

Comment: In C++, reading an uninitialized variable leads to undefined behavior. So there's no use pondering about what value you'll get i you read it.

Comment: To take GMan's comment a bit further, while it is true that `x` could be equal to `0` or could be equal to anything else, it is not meaningful to talk about the probability. It is allowed for all uninitialised values to actually be initialised to a fixed number (often done by debuggers), or it could be set in a way that is highly deterministic based on previous operations. But we can only meaningfully talk about this by looking at matters other than C++ itself, as far as C++ goes, it has nothing to say on the matter. Compliant compilers may leave the probability of `0` at 100%, 0% or anything.

Comment: @GMan and @Jon Hanna: Appreciate your comments. I mentioned that `x` is not initialized. And both of you are right that uninitialized variable may lead to undefined behavior. I also mentioned that, "If you mean "uninitialized", then the answer is no." I made some edits based on your comments. If you have more suggestions, on how can add or edit to improve the answer, I would love to hear your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean with "equal to false". PHP specifically has two different operators. You could say `value == false` meaning that value is a scalar that evaluates to false, and `value === false` in that it is undefined.

Likewise, SQL has `NULL`, which is a special value that is not related to 0 (or FALSE).

C/C++ doesn't really have the concept of "undefined", only "uninitialized", in which case the variable exists, but its value is not defined and should not be read if you want your code to not suck.

In a scalar sense (i.e. IF you have something that holds a value), false is often defined as "0", and true as "non-zero", but that's not a standard across the board.

Comment: In C++, reading an uninitialized variable leads to undefined behavior. (Which makes suckiest code.)

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying. Don't read uninitialized values if you don't want your code to suck.

Comment: Sucky code isn't equivalent to having undefined behavior the former is an implication of the latter. :P (Having UB is a much stronger argument than saying it sucks.)

Comment: Depends on your threshold of suckiness :) But you're right, it should be spelled out to make sure there is no misunderstanding: Reading uninitialized values is undefined behavior and could result in unintended behavior across platforms or configurations, including crashes, incorrect results, you name it. It's actually one of the worst kinds of bugs - it's very common to have code that runs all nice and cool in a debug build and fails miserably in a release build. Have fun debugging that.