# What would be an example of an anaphoric conditional in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, conditional-statements

What would be an example of an anaphoric conditional in Lisp? Please explain the code as well.

Comment: I am only familiar with the term "anaphoric" as it pertains to natural languages -- for example, a pronoun can be considered an anaphoric reference to a previously mentioned noun. "John is a programmer.  He works for Google."  In this example, "he" is an anaphoric reference to "John".  So I think you need to explain what an "anaphoric conditional" means in the context of Lisp programming -- it's not a commonly used term.

Comment: **@Jim_Lewis:** Here's explanation what an "anaphoric conditional" means in the context of Lisp programming: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/06/29/more-literate-programming-language-level-anaphora

Comment: @Jim Lewis: Unsurprisingly, that's precisely what *anaphoric* means when referring to macros. See my answer for links and example.

Comment: Thanks for the links...I get it now!  You learn something new every day around here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example is the Common Lisp `LOOP`:

```
(loop for item in list
      when (general-predicate item)
      collect it)
```

The variable `IT` has the value of the test expression. This is a feature of the ANSI Common Lisp `LOOP` facility.

Example:

```
(loop for s in '("sin" "Sin" "SIN")
      when (find-symbol s)
      collect it)
```

returns

```
 (SIN)
```

because only `"SIN"` is a name for an existing symbol, here the symbol `SIN`. In Common Lisp symbol names have internally uppercase names by default.

Comment: **@Rainer_Joswig:** Wow, thanks -- that was amazingly clear to me. Again, thank you!!

Comment: **@Rainer_Joswig:** From your experience, what has been the best way to learn LISP for you?

Answer (score 10):

Paul Graham's [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) has a chapter on [Anaphoric Macros](http://www.bookshelf.jp/texi/onlisp/onlisp_15.html).

Essentially, it's a shorthand way of writing statements that avoids repeating code. For example, compare:

```
(let ((result (big-long-calculation)))
  (if result
      (foo result)))
```

and

```
(if (big-long-calculation)
    (foo it))
```

where `it` is a special name that refers to whatever was just calculated in `(big-long-calculation)`.

Comment: **@Greg Hewgill:** Thanks, still sort of lost in Paul Graham's code, but it's fun to process.

Comment: @blunders: Indeed. Anaphoric macros probably isn't the best place to start, unless you're already very familiar with the different styles of macros in Lisp. On Lisp is a great read.

Comment: **@Greg Hewgill:** Agree. I've scanned a few LISP books, mainly The Little Schemer, and the like. "Anaphoric conditional" randomly came up in doing research for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920046/is-it-common-for-a-language-to-evalute-undefined-as-equal-to-false-if-so-why-is